# jquery method of selecting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the real difference between the following code:

```
<p>Maizere1</p>
<p>Maizere2</p>
<p>Maizere3</p>
<script>
$("p").text($(this).text()).get(0);

vs

$("<p>").text($(this).text()).get(0);//actually this line is what giving me trouble
```

```
what does $("<p>"> this do?
i heard that $("<p>") will first actually check where the element exist or not ,if not only will create element
```

Comment: if you get you need to alert or console.log it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('<p>')` isn't a valid jquery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) but it will however create a `<p>` element which I don't think is what you're trying to solve here.

Comment: `$("<p>")` will, however, create a new `<p>` element: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @creminsn i heard that $("<p>") will first actually check where the element exist or not ,if not only will create element

Comment: @MaizerePathak, read the linked documentation in my previous comment for exactly what it does.

Answer (score 2):

`$("p")` - select p element
`$("<p>")` - creating p element on the fly

Comment: He means the phrase "on the fly", as in spontaneously.

Answer (score 2):

`$("<p>")` creats a new element and you can use `.append()` to add it to the dom while `$("p")` selects them.

correct is to use `$("<p>")` like this: `$("<p />")`. But jQuery allows both.

Example:

```
<p></p>

$("p").append($("<p>test</p>").addCLass("test"));
```

result:

```
<p class="test">
  <p>test</p>
</p>
```